# Unity3d : How to make the object follow the Player

Tags: triggers, unity-game-engine

Basically I need Coins(GameObject within range) to follow the Player for a period of time, after the Player enters the trigger of a PowerUp(GameObject).
My script is a component of the PowerUp object. The problem is that I don't know how to make the Coins follow the Player, momentarily the PowerUp is following the Player.

```
OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider)
{   
if(other.tag == "Player")
{   
    transform.LookAt(Player);

        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) >= MinDist)
            { 
                transform.position +=      transform.forward*MoveSpeed*Time.deltaTime;
            }
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) <= MaxDist)
            {
                score = score + 5;
                Debug.Log("Player Score" + score);
                Destroy(gameObject);
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

combine both your IF's

you have your min and max checks backwards...

```
currentDist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Player.position)

if (currentDist<max)
  move towards player

if(currentDist<min)
  collect coin

also add a timer
followTime += Time.deltaTime
if (followTime > MaxTime)
  Destroy(this.gameobject)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment yet (new user) I'll post an answer, even though it's more of an elaboration on the answer given by CthulhuJon..

I just wanted to suggest that you calculate the vector between your coin and the player, and move along that vector, rather than having the coin look at the player and moving along it's forward. Example:

```
Vector3 moveDir = player.tranform.position - coin.transform.position;
coin.transform.position += moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

NB: The code is untested, but the idea should be clear.
By doing it this way you can have an animation on your coin (e.g. rotating it around it's local up-axis, typical coin behaviour). Also, if you prefer you can of course still call LookAt(player), but implementing it as I described will be less prone to mistake, I think. Because no matter what you do to that coin, it will still move in the direction that you intend, namely towards the player.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I totally forgot to reply and thank you.
This helped later in the game so thanks again!

Comment: Glad that you could use it for something. :)